# Extract keys and left values from a Map<?, Either> in Javaslang

Tags: functional-programming, vavr

Given a `Map<String, Either<Boolean, Integer>`, what's the most straightforward way to convert it to a `Map<String, Boolean>` containing only the entries with boolean values?

Right now I have this:

```
Map<String, Boolean> boolMap = eitherMap
  .filter(entry -> entry._2.isLeft())
  .map((key, value) -> Tuple.of(key, value.getLeft())
;
```

This works, but seems unnecessarily wordy, and it seems like there should be some tighter, one-step, “flatmap that ” solution.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Javaslang so I don't know the answer outright but it might be possible if Either is a 'biased' container.  If it is unbiased I think your solution might be the simplest one

Comment: @melston Can you clarify what you mean by 'biased container'?

Comment: This is typically used of an Either-like container with one of two possible states.  A biased variant is one where one state is a 'successful' state and the other is an error or failure state.  In this case flatmapping works much like Option where calling flatmap on a None simply returns a None while calling flatmap on a Some(x) operates on the x and continues on.  This approach is often called railway-oriented programming where a failure/none basically halts processing.  So calling flatmap on a success processes the contained value while calling flatmap on failure simply returns the failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I'm the creator of Javaslang

Here is a solution based on javaslang-2.1.0-alpha. We take advantage of the fact that Either is right-biased. Because we focus on the left values, we swap the Either. The flatMap iterates then over the Either, if it contains a boolean.

```
    import javaslang.collection.Map;
    import javaslang.control.Either;

    import static javaslang.API.*;

    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Map<String, Either<Boolean, Integer>> map = Map(
                    "a", Left(true),
                    "b", Right(1),
                    "c", Left(false));

            Map<String, Boolean> result =
                    map.flatMap((s, e) -> e.swap().map(b -> Tuple(s, b)));

            // = HashMap((a, true), (c, false))
            println(result);

        }
    }
```

You achieve the same in javaslang-2.0.5 by using static factory methods like `Tuple.of(s, b)`.